# Allowing mail delivery against a SQL db

Tags: email, mariadb, postfix-mta

My questions is regarding with MIMEDefang and I tried to reach their public mail list but after 1 week nobody accepted my join request. Also, I've already asked similar question to their mail list and i got no answer yet.

I'm trying to change the behavior of our Postfix mail server which is used for e-mail delivery to the customers. It doesn't accept any e-mails from the internet. A couple of weeks ago, the government decided to change mail delivery options for all banking industries. Basically the government add some some basic rules regarding with "gdpr" which should be applied for all outgoing mails to the banking customers. There is an options list to state customers desires about what kind of e-mails allowed to deliver their personal mail accounts. The mails could be 3 or 4 different types. For example, bills for payments, campaign mails, sending and receiving money receipts and so on. The policy says, if a customer specifically states that any of these mail types could send him, we can process it according his/her preferences. On the contrary, if a customer receives any mail other than its preferences the bank will face penalties for that behavior. I decided to use MIMEDefang to achieve this policy. The requirements listed above, drive me to use sql or redis service along with MIMEDefang because this list could change in time. I guess right on the "filter_recipient" time, I have to connect sql db to check whether the user allowed this mail to deliver its personal mail account. Is it possible to use sql (postgresql, mariadb,) with MIMEDefang ? I'm not certain about which callback is the right choice  here to query that. May be "filter_end" is better than "filter_recipient" callback for this particular check because there is another condition which needs to check/determine the type of e-mail.
The second condition is the type of e-mail. I have to look at the contents in the DATA portion of e-mail and find out the type of e-mail. I'm going to tie these two conditions and decide to allow or drop e-mails individually. Also, there are 90K customers and we were delivered 30K mails per day at most.

I would like to ask some questions about SQL and MIMEDefang.

- Is that possible to use SQL queries with MIMEDefang to validate recipients and its preferences ?
- Is there any drawbacks while using SQL services with MIMEDefang ?
- Where can i tie these conditions with each other ? Which callback is eligible to process these two conditions together ?

Comment: I've already setup a test environment on a virtual Debian 10 with Postfix/MIMEDefang and MariaDB. As a testing purpose, there is a db stored in MariaDB which has following setup.
`who` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '', `alias` varchar(50) default NULL, `taglevel1` int(11) default NULL, `taglevel2` int(11) default NULL, `taglevel3` int(11) default NULL, `taglevel4` int(11) default NULL, `taglevel5` int(11) default NULL, UNIQUE KEY `prefs_who` (`who`)

Comment: Hi again,
I partially solved this design issue and can verify recipient email address from MariaDB during in delivery time. I used below link as a reference point to start.  
"https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477653/how-to-install-mimedefang-on-debian"